# Gunicorn as Service not recognizing Python dependencies

Tags: python-3.x, flask, unix, gunicorn

I am running a Flask app on a Ubuntu Linode Server using Gunicorn to serve the app and nginx as a reverse proxy.

I have one app running successfully, but I have a second app where I'm running in to the following problem.

### What does work

- when I run `FLASK_APP=tester.py python3 -m flask run`

This works, tester.py runs the app bound to 0.0.0.0 on port 5100 and I can access it from my browser.

- when I run `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5100 wsgi:app`

This also works, as my wsgi.py imports my app object making it accessible for wsgi

### Useful details

- `which python` gives me `/usr/bin/python`
- `which pip` gives `/usr/bin/pip` and `which pip3` gives `/usr/bin/pip3`
- `which python3` gives me `/usr/bin/python3`
- `which gunicorn` gives me `/usr/bin/gunicorn`
- I am not using a virtual environment since boths app have near identical dependencies

### What's not working

I created a service for forwarding traffic with nginx with:

**/etc/systemd/system/testpad.service**

```
[Unit]
#  specifies metadata and dependencies
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve myproject
After=network.target

# tells the init system to only start this after the networking target has been reached
# We will give our regular user account ownership of the process since it owns all of the relevant files
[Service]

# Service specify the user and group under which our process will run.
User=www-data

# give group ownership to the www-data group so that Nginx can communicate easily with the Gunicorn processes.
Group=www-data

# We'll then map out the working directory and set the PATH environmental variable so that the init system knows where our the executabl>
WorkingDirectory=/home/xxx/xxx

# We'll then specify the commanded to start the service
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gunicorn --bind unix:testpad.sock --access-logfile /home/xxx/xxx/accesslog --error-logfile /home/xxx/xxx/errorlog -m 007 wsgi:app


# This will tell systemd what to link this service to if we enable it to start at boot. We want this service to start when the regular m>

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

when I start the service it runs for a second then I get this from `sudo systemctl status testpad`

```
 testpad.service - Gunicorn instance to serve myproject
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/testpad.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-09-06 15:47:59 UTC; 16min ago
    Process: 655575 ExecStart=/usr/bin/gunicorn --bind unix:testpad.sock --access-logfile /home/xxx/xxx/acces>
   Main PID: 655575 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 06 15:47:54 microportalbeta systemd[1]: Started Gunicorn instance to serve myproject.
Sep 06 15:47:59 microportalbeta systemd[1]: testpad.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 06 15:47:59 microportalbeta systemd[1]: testpad.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

so when I `cat errorlog` I get

```
[2021-09-06 15:21:31 +0000] [655222] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 655222)
[2021-09-06 15:21:31 +0000] [655223] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 384, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from run import app
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from genedflask import create_app, db
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/xxx/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from flask_login import LoginManager
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_login'
[2021-09-06 15:21:31 +0000] [655223] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 655223)
[2021-09-06 15:21:32 +0000] [655220] [WARNING] Worker with pid 655223 was terminated due to signal 15
[2021-09-06 15:21:32 +0000] [655220] [WARNING] Worker with pid 655222 was terminated due to signal 15
[2021-09-06 15:21:32 +0000] [655220] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2021-09-06 15:21:32 +0000] [655220] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
[2021-09-06 15:23:34 +0000] [655249] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2021-09-06 15:23:34 +0000] [655249] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2021-09-06 15:23:35 +0000] [655249] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2021-09-06 15:23:36 +0000] [655249] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2021-09-06 15:23:37 +0000] [655249] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2021-09-06 15:23:38 +0000] [655249] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2021-09-06 15:23:39 +0000] [655249] [ERROR] Can't connect to testpad.sock
[2021-09-06 15:28:44 +0000] [655315] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2021-09-06 15:28:44 +0000] [655315] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2021-09-06 15:28:45 +0000] [655315] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2021-09-06 15:28:46 +0000] [655315] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2021-09-06 15:28:47 +0000] [655315] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2021-09-06 15:28:48 +0000] [655315] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2021-09-06 15:28:49 +0000] [655315] [ERROR] Can't connect to testpad.sock
[2021-09-06 15:31:09 +0000] [655348] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2021-09-06 15:31:09 +0000] [655348] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2021-09-06 15:31:10 +0000] [655348] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2021-09-06 15:31:11 +0000] [655348] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2021-09-06 15:31:12 +0000] [655348] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2021-09-06 15:31:13 +0000] [655348] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2021-09-06 15:31:14 +0000] [655348] [ERROR] Can't connect to testpad.sock
[2021-09-06 15:33:34 +0000] [655387] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2021-09-06 15:33:34 +0000] [655387] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2021-09-06 15:33:35 +0000] [655387] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2021-09-06 15:33:36 +0000] [655387] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2021-09-06 15:33:37 +0000] [655387] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2021-09-06 15:33:38 +0000] [655387] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2021-09-06 15:33:39 +0000] [655387] [ERROR] Can't connect to testpad.sock
[2021-09-06 15:47:54 +0000] [655575] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2021-09-06 15:47:54 +0000] [655575] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2021-09-06 15:47:55 +0000] [655575] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2021-09-06 15:47:56 +0000] [655575] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2021-09-06 15:47:57 +0000] [655575] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2021-09-06 15:47:58 +0000] [655575] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2021-09-06 15:47:59 +0000] [655575] [ERROR] Can't connect to testpad.sock
```

Not sure why it is not finding flask-login as it is installed under pip and pip3 globally, and is visible when I run pip3 list or pip list.

I assume that once I overcome this hurdle then the testpad.sock file should auto create as it did with my previous app. Most people with this problem I found it was an issue with gunicorn looking at the global environment when people installed dependencies in a virtual environment, which I am not doing in this circumstance.

Any suggestions?

#### Update

I never did figure out why it could not find the libraries when ran as a service, I even set the PYTHONPATH variable to see if that would help.

What I did do is give up on running as a service and instead just ran the application as a background process on port 8000 and just directed nginx to forward traffic there, and that worked.